# Prove that, $ H \cdot N $ is the subgroup of $ G $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Task:
Suppose that $ H $ is a subgroup of $ G $ and $ N $ is normal subgroup of $ G $. Show that, $ H \cdot N $ is a subgroup of $ G .$

Idea:
Firsly I think, that I should write: $ H \cdot N = \{h\cdot n : h \in H, n \in N \} $ but I don't know if this is a good way.

Comment: What are the steps to check a subset is a subgroup? Do them...

Comment: I know conditions to check, but I want to know, if this good way.

Comment: Yes checking the conditions is a good way. It's **the** way. Unless you were talking about writing down the set-builder notation for $HN$; that's not a "way" it's just a definition.

Comment: well, $H \cdot N$ is *defined* as that set, so that is the form you will need to work with to show it is a subgroup. you need to show that set, that is elements of the form $hn$, satisfy the conditions to be a subgroup

Comment: What is the problem? Look up the definition of a subgroup and the conditions that a subset of a group is itself a group, and then try to verify them. What other way could there be?

Comment: what is a nautral subgroup? Do you mean a normal subgroup? Anyway $HN$ is only a subgroup not "the" subgroup as every group has at least 2 subgroups

Comment: Yes, normal, my fault. I try to prove them, one moment.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis xcept for unique (up to isomorphism) group having precisly one subgroup ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  if the group itself is not trivial then $G$ and $\{1\}$ are subgroups of $G$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

Let $\,G\,$ be a group, $\,H,K\le G\;$ . The set $\,HK\,$ is a subgroup of $\,G\,$ iff $\,HK=KH\;$

The above is fulfilled if, for example, one of the two subgroups $\,H,K\;$ is *normal*

Comment: If I prove that $ HK = KH $, so I prove my task?

Comment: Indeed so...but the lemma mentioned in my second line must be proved first, of course.

Comment: My method: Let $ h_1, h_2 \in H \ n_1, n_2 \in N $. $$ i) (n_1h_1)^{-1} = h_1^{-1}n_1^{-1} \in HN $$  $$ (n_1h_1)^{-1} =  h_1^{-1}n_1^{-1} =(h_1^{-1}n_1^{-1}h_1)h_1^{-1}$$ $ h_1^{-1} \in H $ and $ h_1^{-1}n^{-1}h \in N $ because it's in normal subgroup, so $ (n_1h_1)^{-1} $ $$ ii) e_G \in HN $$ it's easy, because $ e = e \cdot e \Rightarrow e \in HN $ $$ iii) n_1h_1n_2h_2 \in HN $$ We check: $ n_1h_1n_2h_2 = n_1(h_1n_2h_1^{-1})(h_1h_2) $ We know, that $ n_1(h_1n_2h_1^{-1}) \in N $, because N is normal subgroup,and of course $ (h_1h_2) \in H $, because H is subgroup, so $ n_1h_1n_2h_2 \in HN $

Comment: Looks fine to me...+1

Comment: Ok, thank you so much :)